# Using Rails Test Syntax in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

Like most people, I have learned Rails before Ruby and now I would like to get a better knowledge of Ruby.
I am making some scripts and I would like to test them.
I was surprised by the fact that you can't use Rails' test syntax in plain ruby scripts. The following code does not work:

```
require "test/unit"
class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  test "one plus one should be equal to two" do
    assert_equal 1 + 1, 2
  end
end

# Error: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2) (ArgumentError)
```

You have to use this code instead:

```
require "test/unit"
class MyTest < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def one_plus_one_should_be_equal_to_two
    assert_equal 1 + 1, 2
  end
end
```

Which seems less readable to me.
Is it possible to use the "declarative" syntax in plain Ruby scripts?

Comment: Another option is rspec which let's you write specs like your first version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to Rails' APIs, the `test` method is defined inside [ActiveSupport::Testing::Declarative](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Testing/Declarative.html#method-i-test)  module and uses a sort of metaprogramming to add new test methods.

If you don't already have the Rails gem installed, you can just install the activesupport gem:

```
gem install activesupport
```

Now you just have to require it and make your class inherit from `ActiveSupport::TestCase`.
Here is the complete code:

```
require "test/unit"
require "active_support"
class MyTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "one plus one should be equal to two" do
    assert_equal 1 + 1, 2
  end
end
```